# Computing principal curvatures in local coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I was wondering how to compute the principal curvatures when working with a local parametrization. (Context: Surfaces, i.e. 2-dim Manifolds). Since I have formulas for the Gaussian and the mean curvature, I used them to derive:

$$k_i = H \pm \sqrt{H^2 - K} \, ,$$

where the $k_i$ denote the two principal curvatures, K the Gaussian curvature and H the mean curvature. Now when looking through the Wikipedia page about [Differential geometry of surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces#First_and_second_fundamental_forms,_the_shape_operator,_and_the_curvature) I saw a different formula (in the bottom row of the table I have linked):

$$k_i = \frac{H \pm \sqrt{H^2 - 4K}}{2}.$$

Now I have two questions:

1. Why is the formula different? Is it a different context? As far as I could tell everything else matches what I am working with...
2. Is there a better way to compute the principal curvatures when working with local coordinates? Using the formulas for the Gaussian and mean curvature is pretty straight forward, which I like, but it does involve a lot of computation. Maybe there is a more effective way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It seems that in your formulas the definition of the mean curvature differs. There is a choice to be made and both options are equally valid and are used in the literature. One way would be be
   $$\frac{\kappa_1+\kappa_2}{2}=H,$$
   i.e. $H$ is the mean of the principal curvatures. The other option is that $H$ is the sum of the principal curvatures, i.e.
   $$\kappa_1+\kappa_2=H.$$
   Wikipedia uses this version.
   Since the underlying math and geometry is not really changed, both version are valid. Only the calculations may differ here and there.
2. You could calculate the principal curvatures as the eigenvalues of the second fundamental form. It may be a bit shorter, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_curvature

Comment: Ah I see, the answer to 1) makes total sense. Regarding 2), aren't the principal curvatures the eigenvalues of the Weingarten map? But I see that in your link it says it's the eigenvalues of the second fundamental form... How is the connection there?

Comment: @ noam.szyfer: You are correct, it is the Weingarten map, which is the inverse of the metric tensor multiplied (in a matrix sense) to the second fundamental form. In the wiki-link the second fundamental form was calculated w.r.t. to an orthonormal basis. W.r.t. to an orthonormal basis the metric tensor is just the identity. Hence in this special setting the second fundamental form and the Weingarten map coincide.

Comment: ok, so then in order to compute the principal curvatures i would have to compute both fundamental forms, then compute $W = G^-1 \cdot H$ just to get the Weingarten map, and then compute its eigenvalues? Because in general, if i take $f_x$ and $f_y$ as a basis of $T_pM$, where $f_x$ is the partial in first direction and $f_y$ in second direction, won't be orthonormal in general. Right?

Comment: @noam.szyfer: Correct, That's why this is computationally always kind of a hassle as already pointed out in DIdier_ answer.

Comment: ok, thanks! I have a last question: I looked all the stuff up in do carmo, and there he has the equation $W = -H \cdot G^{-1}$, and not $W = G^{-1} \cdot H$ as above. The minus sign comes from the fact that $W$ is not the Weingarten map in his chapter, but the differential of the Gauss map. But why is the multiplication flipped? Is it commutative in this case? I can't seem to see why, and I also can't find something wrong in the book. Do you know the reason?

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I found the difference. (I'll leave the question and my answer here in case anyone in the future encounters the same problem...): I misquoted do carmo, the reason is that he writes the matrix explicitly, i.e. the matrix-entries with indices and it's actually $W^T$, the transpose of $W$. Then there is no problem: $(W^T)^T = (-H \cdot G^{-1})^T \iff W = (G^{-1})^T \cdot H^T \iff W = G^{-1} \cdot H$, since G and H are symmetric.

Comment: @ humanStampedist thank you a lot for your answers, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of convention on what you call the mean curvature $H$.

Suppose $\Sigma^2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is an embedded surface and $S$ is its shape operator. Then the principal curvatures are the eigenvalues of $S$ (and the principal curvature directions are the corresponding eigen directions).

Some author refer to the mean curvature $H$ as the trace of $S$, that is, the sum of the principal curvatures, while some others refer to $H$ as the mean of the principal curvatures, that is, in dimension $2$, $\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{trace}S$.

Changing $H$ by $H/2$ in your first formula gives the second.

Concerning the computations of the principal curvatures: it is in general a hard and impossible problem because it leads to computing eigenvalues of an endomorphism and roots of a polynomial, which we know is impossible in degree greater than 5. But in dimension $2$, the formula you gave is just the usual formula for computing the roots of a degree 2 polynomial!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I can see now the possibilities there are to compute the principal curvatures (see comments on the other posts), but it's helpful to know that it is difficult in general. Thanks!